# Add pushpin in bing map for different zip codes

Tags: jquery, asp.net, bing-maps

I want to add pushpin to different zip code that we have in my array zip Codes below. As per current code this is only displaying boundaries of Zip code but i want to add pushpin with boundaries. Also, i want to want to add center so all Zip code pushpin information can be view by users. [Reference URL Of bing Map, that i have used](https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk/sdsloadmultipleboundaries#JS)

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
    function GetMap() {
         var  map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('divMap'), {
            credentials: bmKey,
            center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(27.994402, -81.760254),        
            zoom: 7,
        });
      // Below zip code will be display on map
        var zipCodes = ['27006', '27007', '27009', '27011', '27012', '27013', '27014','27016'];
            var geoDataRequestOptions = {
                entityType: 'Postcode1',
                getAllPolygons: false
            };
            Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.SpatialDataService', function () {
                //Use the GeoData API manager to get the boundary
                Microsoft.Maps.SpatialDataService.GeoDataAPIManager.getBoundary(zipCodes, geoDataRequestOptions, map, function (data) {
                    if (data.results && data.results.length > 0) {
                        map.entities.push(data.results[0].Polygons);
                         
                        var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(data.results[0], {
                            title: 'test text',
                            subTitle: ' ',
                            text: '1'
                        });
                        
                        map.entities.push(pin);
                    }
                }, null, function errCallback(callbackState, networkStatus, statusMessage) {
                    console.log(callbackState);
                    console.log(networkStatus);
                    console.log(statusMessage);
                });
            });
    
    </script>
    




 <!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                 <div id='printoutPanel'></div>
            
            <div id='myMap' style='width: 100vw; height: 100vh;'></div>
    
     </form>
      <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?key=XXXXXXXXXXXX&callback=GetMap'
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the center of a polygon using the `centroid` function of the Spatial math module: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/modules/spatial-math-module/geometry-calculations

Something like the following will likely do what you are looking for:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function GetMap() {
         var  map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('divMap'), {
            credentials: bmKey,
            center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(27.994402, -81.760254),        
            zoom: 7,
        });
      // Below zip code will be display on map
        var zipCodes = ['27006', '27007', '27009', '27011', '27012', '27013', '27014','27016'];
            var geoDataRequestOptions = {
                entityType: 'Postcode1',
                getAllPolygons: false
            };
            Microsoft.Maps.loadModule(['Microsoft.Maps.SpatialDataService', 'Microsoft.Maps.SpatialMath'], function () {
                //Use the GeoData API manager to get the boundary
                Microsoft.Maps.SpatialDataService.GeoDataAPIManager.getBoundary(zipCodes, geoDataRequestOptions, map, function (data) {
                    if (data.results && data.results.length > 0) {
                        map.entities.push(data.results[0].Polygons);

                        //Get the centroid of the polygons.
                        var centroid = Microsoft.Maps.SpatialMath.Geometry.centroid(data.results[0].Polygons);
                        var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(centroid, {
                            title: 'test text',
                            subTitle: ' ',
                            text: '1'
                        });
                        
                        map.entities.push(pin);
                    }
                }, null, function errCallback(callbackState, networkStatus, statusMessage) {
                    console.log(callbackState);
                    console.log(networkStatus);
                    console.log(statusMessage);
                });
            });
    
    </script>
    




 <!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                 <div id='printoutPanel'></div>
            
            <div id='myMap' style='width: 100vw; height: 100vh;'></div>
    
     </form>
      <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?key=XXXXXXXXXXXX&callback=GetMap'
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Microsoft.Maps.SpatialMath.centroid(data.results[0].Polygons); as per document this accept Lat Long not ZIP code

Comment: Microsoft.MMaps.SpatialMath.centroid is not a function

Comment: Correct. It's `Microsoft.Maps.SpatialMath.Geometry.centroid`